# Data from firebase is not displayed angular 2 beta

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to display the data from firebase when a button is clicked but it is not displayed. Below are the 3 files that I have written.

**firebase.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Http, Response } from 'angular2/http';

const myFirebase = 'https://*****.firebaseio.com';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {
    constructor(private _http: Http) {}

    getPages() {
        return this._http.get(myFirebase + '/pages_name.json')
            .map((res:Response) => res.json());
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { FirebaseService } from '../../../firebase.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: require('./app.template.html'),
    providers: [
        FirebaseService
    ]
})

export class LoginTest {
    public pages;

    constructor(private _firebaseService: FirebaseService) {}

    onGetPages() {
        this._firebaseService.getPages()
            .subscribe(
                data => { this.pages = data},
                error => console.log(error)
            );
    }
}
```

**app.template.html**

```
<div class="fixed_width" id="sec2_holder">
    <div id="get-pages">
        <h2 style="color: white">Get Pages</h2>
        <button (click)="onGetPages()">Get Pages</button>
    </div>
    <ul>
       <li *ngFor="#page of pages">{{page.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the branch in my firebase:
[pages in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PTsd.jpg)

Anything wrong with my code?

Comment: What version of `angular2` are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.0.0-beta.15

Comment: Besides that it is advisable to update, can you change `data => { this.pages = data}` to `data => { console.log(data)}`, and add the output in your answer

Comment: The output is:
Object {about: true, contact: true, home: true, projects: true}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the response of your firebase call is not an array. Change your `onGetPages` implementation to something like this, to create an array from your result object:

```
onGetPages() {
   this._firebaseService.getPages().subscribe(
     (data) => { 
         this.pages = [];
         for(let name in data) {
            if(data.hasOwnProperty(name) && data[name]) {
               this.pages.push(name);
            }
         }
     },
     error => console.log(error)
  );
}
```